# Using an unless or if statement on an instance variable (Ruby)

Tags: ruby

I am creating an Elevator object with an instance that can only go between floors one and twelve.  The code works for the up and down instance methods, but I cannot get the elevator to not go above floor 12 or below floor 1.  I tried using unless @floor >= 12, but there was a syntax error.  I'm sure it is simple, but I am new to Ruby.

Here is the code that works:

```
class Elevator
  @@count = @floor
  #The Constructor Method
  def initialize(floor) #floor is an instance variable of the Elevator object.
    @floor = floor
    cheery_greeting
  end

  def cheery_greeting
    puts "Hello my friend! would you like to go up or down?"
  end

  def self.notify()
    "You are now on floor #{@@count}"
  end

  #accessor methods
  def go_up
      @floor += 1
      notify
  end

  def go_down
      @floor -= 1
      notify
  end
```

I want to add a break so that it stops iterating when we reach floor twelve, so I wrote this, but it wouldn't even puts.

```
  def floor_limit
    if @@count == 12
      puts "You're Way Too High!"
    end
```

I also tried:

```
  def go_up
        unless @floor >= 12    
    @floor += 1
    notify
  end
```

Comment: I'm gonna guess that you're coming from Python, you seem to be excluding `end` statements to close out your blocks.  Both of the efforts you say you tried need an `end` for the conditional, and another `end` for the method definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing class instance variables with instance variables here and that's going to lead to trouble and confusion. If you're new to Ruby I strongly advise you to avoid using class instance variables, they just lead to a lot of mess. Instead focus on making each instance as self-contained as possible.

To make this more Ruby you can do a few things:

```
class Elevator
  # Define a valid range for this elevator
  FLOOR_RANGE_DEFAULT = (1..12)

  # Expose the current floor and range as properties
  attr_reader :floor
  attr_reader :range

  def initialize(floor, range = nil)
    @floor = floor.to_i
    @range = (range || FLOOR_RANGE_DEFAULT).to_a
  end

  def inspect
    @range.map do |floor|
      if (@floor == floor)
        '[%d]' % floor
      else
        ' %d ' % floor
      end
    end.join(' ')
  end
end
```

Then your up and down code can check limits and reject if that's an invalid operation. First separate the moving code from the code that interprets up or down:

```
def up
  move(@floor + 1)
end

def down
  move(@floor - 1)
end

def move(target)
  if (@range.include?(target))
    @floor = target
  end

  @floor
end
```

Now you have a framework that you can build on. By using simple things like Ruby's range feature you can make a very adaptable class that can handle situations like elevators that have other limits:

```
e = Elevator.new(1, (1..20))
```

Or that stop only on odd floors:

```
e = Elevator.new(1, (1..20).select(&:odd?))
```

Or skip the 4th, 13th and 14th:

```
e = Elevator.new(1, (1..20).to_a - [ 4, 13, 14 ])
```

It doesn't take more code, it just takes the right code.

Comment: Yeah, that makes a lot of sense.  This is really helpful, as I am trying not just to complete this one assignment, but also to build general programming logic skills.  I was only using procedural code until last week, but I'm now seeing how useful and flexible objects can be.  Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The following should do the trick.

```
def go_up
    @floor += 1 unless @floor >= 12    
    notify
end
```

Or like this:

```
def go_up
    @floor += 1 if @floor < 12    
    notify
end
```

They are both pretty intuitive so it's up to you.

[This](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2008/12/01/unless-the-abused-ruby-conditional/) is a pretty detailed explanation on when to use `unless`.
And [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_if_else.htm) is a standard if/else/unless tutorial.

Comment: It's not clear if the conditional should apply just to the move, or to the move/notify combo.

Comment: Yup, I wasn't sure from the question. That's why I added the extra resources on conditionals.

Comment: I had the unless statement in the wrong place!  Thanks Justin.  I knew it was something simple that I was overlooking.

Comment: I was only using JS before and this is my first week with Ruby, so the syntax trips me up a bit, although I think I'll like it better once I get used to it.

Now if I wanted to change the message to let the user know that 1 and 12 are the limits, would I so that inside of the go_up and go_down instance methods?

Comment: @MatthewMacDermant, I'd suggest working through tadman's answer. It will definitely help you in the long run. For your question: [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_if_else.htm) tutorial shows you how to write regular if statements (as opposed to the single line statements I posted)